# How to solve this length integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function, curves

I have to solve this integral in order to calculate the length of a curve

$L(\gamma) = 2\alpha\int_0^L \sqrt{e^t +1} dt$

I tried with some substitutions, like $e^t +1 = u$ and others, but the calculations get difficult and the result I get is different from the book's one ($L(\gamma) = 2\sqrt{2}\alpha sinh(L)$)

Comment: Hint: try $u = \sqrt{e^t + 1}$.

Comment: You will find a solution in the answer of (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/728215).

Answer (score 1):

Let $u = \sqrt{e^t + 1}$ following the comment by @Gribouillis

$t=\log \left(u^2-1\right)$

$dt = \dfrac{2 u \,du}{u^2-1}$

The integral becomes

$$L(\gamma)=4 a \int_{\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{e^L+1}} \dfrac{u^2}{u^2-1} \, du$$

$$\int \frac{u^2}{u^2-1} \, du=\int \frac{\left(u^2-1\right)+1}{u^2-1} \, du=\int \left(\frac{1}{u^2-1}+1\right) \, du=$$

$$=u+\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{u-1}{u+1}\right)$$

Therefore
$$L(\gamma)=4 a \left[u+\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{u-1}{u+1}\right)\right]_{\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{e^L+1}}=4 a \left(\sqrt{e^L+1}+\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{\sqrt{e^L+1}-1}{\sqrt{e^L+1}+1}\right)-\sqrt{2}-\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{1+\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)=2 a \left(2 \sqrt{e^L+1}+\log \left(\sqrt{e^L+1}-1\right)-\log \left(\sqrt{e^L+1}+1\right)\\-2 \sqrt{2}-\log \left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)+\log \left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)\right)$$

Comment: It seems right but the result is different... Maybe we have to do some simplifications?

Comment: I tried but with no success. Anyway plugging values for $a$ and $L$ the approximated values are the same

Answer (score 1):

I can simplify the solution of @Raffaele in the sense of reducing the clutter. So let's take it from

$$
\begin{align}
\int \frac{u^2}{u^2-1}
&=u+\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{u-1}{u+1}\right)\\
&=u-\tanh^{-1}u
\end{align}
$$

Then the complete solution is given by

$$
\begin{align}
L(\gamma) 
&= 2\alpha\int_0^L \sqrt{e^t +1} dt\\
&=4\alpha\left[\sqrt{e^L + 1}-\sqrt{2}-\tanh^{-1}\left(\sqrt{e^L + 1}\right) +\tanh^{-1}\sqrt{2} \right]\\
\end{align}
$$

I have verified this solution by comparison with direct numerical simulation of the integral. In addition, I can say unequivocally that the answer profferred from the book is *erroneous*.

Comment: Maybe I got the previous calculations wrong... The exercise text says that I have to calculate the length of $\gamma : [-L,L]\to\mathbb{R}^3$, $$\gamma (t) = (\alpha cosh(t)cos(t), \alpha cosh(t)sin(t),\alpha t)$$ , $t \in [-L,L]$ with $L > 0 $ and $\alpha \ge 0$

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake... now I get the same result of the book